# Simplest example for setting up asp-items without getting "the name does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, html-select

I'm a person who has done some simple web programming in the past but now as I return to it and try to create a simple single page app with a form in it that has a "select" in it I'm unable to get beyond a "**The name does not exist in the current context**" error in my cshtml file. I've selected to do a .NET Core Razor (non-MVC) web app with Visual Studio. Everything I've coded is in two files: Index.cshtml and Index.cshtml.cs and I'm trying to keep it that simple and not implement any Controllers or use lambda syntax - really anything that isn't very plain or dead simple - because my app doesn't need it and I'm trying to limit how much new technology I have to take in to get this simple app done. I think I understand Model Binding because I've gotten it to work for me in these two files when a "select" wasn't being defined. I've been able to bind things like the machineSN you see in the below. I'm trying to bind a List of strings that are in my Index.cshtml.cs file to a "select" statement in my Index.cshtml file.

in Index.cshtml.cs ...

```
[BindProperties]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{

public string machineSN = "123456789";
public string machineModel;
public List<SelectListItem> machineModels = new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem {Text="Unknown", Value="0"},
    new SelectListItem {Text="Omega", Value="1"),
}
:
:
```

in Index.cshtml ...

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
<div class="text-left">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        Machine S/N: <input type="text" name="machineSN" asp-for="machineSN" />
        Model: <select name="machineModel" asp-for="machineModel" asp-items="machineModels"></select>
    </form>
</div>
```

I get the error message when I hover over the squiggly red line that Visual Studio superimposes under the asp-items string in the cshtml.

I've tried giving other types of things to asp-items - things like a SelectList and an IEnumerable but I still get the error message. I'd prefer to see an answer only involving SelectListItems if that's possible. I've seen posts where people fill the "lists" they give asp-items from databases and OnGet()s but can you show me how to do it in the simple case I've laid out above? Thanks very much for any advice that leads me to a simple solution. I've been wasting a lot of time trying to figure out this error message.

Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to put `Model.`. You can see an example of how to use the select tag helper in the [asp.net docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-select-tag-helper).

So, in your case, you would need to update your select to:

`<select asp-for="machineModel" asp-items="Model.machineModels"></select>`

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks very much Juan. A question though, Why was it necessary to do that for machineModels but not for machineSN? Also, I had tried "IndexModel." where you suggested I try "Model." and it didn't work. What is the "Model." really doing? Thanks again!

Comment: `Model` is the variable name of the model object that the page receives for rendering. In `asp-for` you are telling the tag helper which name to give to the field, which will be used by the binder on a post to load the value in that property (btw, you can remove the name attribute from the select). Basically you are just passing a string, not the property itself. In `asp-items` you are passing the tag helper a list of items to use, so you need to get that from the model. Reminder: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue :)

Comment: Ok, I understand why asp-for is different than asp-items. Still a little hazy on Model. What is significant about "Model" versus "IndexModel"? My model is named IndexModel, not Model.

Comment: IndexModel is the type of your model, the class name. On top of your `Index.cshtml` you wrote `@model IndexModel`, there you are defining that the type of your model is `IndexModel`, and the way to access the specific instance of it on the page is through the variable (actually it's a property, but for simplicity consider it a variable) `Model`

Comment: I'm almost there, thanks for bearing with me. I understand now that it wants a "variable" name versus a type name - but where or what gives anything the name "Model". My code doesn't do it anywhere. UPDATE: I see in the Razor syntax documentation that the @model directive in my cshtml file always - per the Razor specification - creates a property named Model that is intended to be used as you helped me to see. Thanks Juan, I'll mark the answer as accepted.